# "I thought we talked..." vs. "I thought we had talked..."

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past

I'm not a native English speaker and I find English quite difficult and confusing and one of the reasons is because of its tenses—which I find challenging and rewarding once everything becomes clear—so I would like to ask which of these two are correct:

> 1. I thought we **talked** about this before
> 2. I thought we **had talked** about this before

I've read somewhere that I should use the past perfect tense to indicate past action that occurred prior to another past action, and Past perfect verbs are always formed by using adding ‘had’ before the past participle form of the verb.

E.g. had + talked

In the examples above, "thought" and "talked" are both past actions, but "talked" happened before "thought", so my guess is that sentence no. 2 is the correct one, but I'm not so sure because sentence no. 1 is used most of the time in movies and conversation.

What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You can search with "past/past perfect or whatever tense you like" and get a bunch of excellent answers.

Comment: Hey, even native English speakers find the English language difficult. Too many rules and exceptions to rules. Plus one for you, for hanging in there. By the way, your question is well phrased. Many English speakers would have difficulty phrasing your question as well as you did. Don

Comment: @Rathony vote against duplicate, this is not about a niche example of native speakers in some regions using the past perfect in an expression, but a general question about whether to use PS or PP, and the other question confuses rather than gives clarity to the issue.

Comment: @Some_Guy This kind of question has been asked many times and I might have chosen the wrong duplicate. That's why I encouraged him to search more with key words that contain tenses. They have to make an effort first to see whether their question has an answer by searching here. If they still have doubts, they can post a question. That seems to be the way this site is being managed. If he had a better context, I would not have closevoted it. Regarding the context, please see my comment below the answer.

Comment: @Rathony I'm looking at the question which you linked, and it isn't a duplicate of that.    I believe the question was asked in good faith, and it's very demotivating to get a question closed whilst being linked to something is only tangentially related to your question.

Comment: @Rathony Also, looking at the question, it's actually more nuanced that I initially thought, because technically *thought* here is in the past simple, so should any action before the thought be in the past perfect?  Good luck finding a duplicate which addresses this.

Comment: @Some_Guy Did you take a look at the second answer of the question? I think that answer is far better than your primarily opinion-based answer here and that answer can fully explain what the OP is asking about. (Actually I am considering downvoting your answer). You don't have to wish me good luck as I did what I think was the right thing to do. You sound like you are the one who is confused with tenses.

Comment: @Rathony My answer is straight out of any grammar book.  Past perfect is used to place events before an established past time.  Past simple is used to put discreet events before the present.  I'm not trying to start a flame war here, just be helpful.

Comment: Hey guys please don't argue, both of you helped me - Some_Guys's answer and Rathony's suggested link - so please let's all be friends here. I also apologize because I didn't know that this question had a related question and had already been asked before. I just registered here a 4 hours ago. Let's chill ok? Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @Francois lol, thanks for stepping in.  Rathony can we kiss and make up please?  Kissing is optional.

Comment: @Francois could you give some context in your question as to when you would use this sentence?  As rathony pointed out below, "I think" may be more appropriate than "I thought".

Comment: @Some_Guy Then, why do you think the OP is confused if he can find such a straight out answer from any grammar book? Did you quote all the quoted sentences from a grammar book, especially the second one ? Which grammar book? Can you name the source in your answer, possibly any link?

Comment: @Rathony I think the implementation of the past perfect is always a difficult concept that trips up even some native speakers (who often default to the past simple, and occasionally use the past perfect entirely inappropriately), and so I contextualised the rules in my answer to illustrate the distinction.  I didn't mean to offend anyone.  Do you have a problem with me, or the answer I gave, because I'm happy to justify it further if you like but it seems more that you're just personally taking issue with me rather than my post.

Comment: @Some_Guy Not at all. I just wanted to know if you quoted those sentences from any grammar book because the sentences didn't look like very good examples. That's all. Shall we stop here? Also, I didn't downvote your answer. I don't do downvote on answers unless I am really pissed-off. Cheers!

Comment: I believe the question is better suited for our sister site ELL, [English Language Learners.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

As is so often the case, the context in which something is said is the main determiner of which tense is appropriate. Correctness of tense may be important, but not nearly as important as being understood, *n'est-ce pas*?

For example, if two people are conversing, and one person brings up a subject unnecessarily (at least in the opinion of the other person), the person who objects to the repetition might say,

> I thought we talked about this before.

Meaning: Why are you bringing this up again? We talked about ___________ before.

On the other hand, imagine the same two people conversing, and one of them, in looking back on an incident which occurred, say, a day ago, says

> I thought we had talked about this before.

If the context of this remark is such that the speaker is considering some past action of his and is telling another person what he was thinking of at that particular time, then the meaning of the words would be slightly different.

In other words, he is looking back and referring to an action which had *already been completed*. This context is slightly different from the context in which the speaker is simply referring in the present to something which has *already been done*. No qualifying verb such as "had talked" would then be needed.

It's a slippery concept, to be sure, and one which even native speakers do not always grasp. However, the shades and nuances of meaning can be important when precision in communication is needed. In normal, everyday conversation, though, such precision is not usually that important.

Comment: I would rather say "I think we talked about this before" when two people are conversing at this moment. You don't even have to use "I thought". I think the context was a bit misleading. (I don't say, "I thought the context was misleading").

Comment: @Rathony: Good point! We Yanks do tend at times to overcomplicate things! Don

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation rhetorician, now I'm quite getting it, still need more practice :)

Comment: Thanks too Rathony, that was brief yet crystal clear explanation :)

Comment: Oh by the way Rathony, why did you say "I think the context was a bit misleading. (I don't say, "I thought the context was misleading")" instead of "I think the context IS a bit misleading. (I DIDN'T say, "I thought the context was misleading")

Comment: @Francois Because the action of "thinking" is occurring at the present, ***now***. That's why you say "I think you were wrong/right." You don't say "I thought you were wrong/right". Likewise, if you are having a conversation with somebody ***NOW***, you don't usually say "I thought" unless a specific past time is mentioned to indicate the action of "thinking" occurred in the past. For example, "I thought 2 days ago that we had talked about it before." Here, it is optional to use "had talked" as it doesn't really make any big difference and it is not confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, that was clear as crystal explanation :) Opps should I should I say "that is a crystal clear explanation" since your written explanation explanation is still visible in my eyes?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

1) Past perfect is used to set the time of an event before *a previously mentioned past time* (or a past time that is clearly implied to all speakers)

2) Past simple is used simply to place an event *before the present*.

**So, for the first case:**

> I know we talked about it earlier, but I thought we had talked about it before.

Because the second talk precedes a previous, also in the past, event.

or

> Why did you bring that up this morning?  I thought we had talked about it before.

Because the talk precedes a defined time of "this morning"

**For the second case:**

> Do we have to talk about this now?  I think we talked about it earlier.

In this case the second talk precedes the present, so past simple is used.

I hope this helps :)

---

Notice how it is rarely "wrong" to use past simple when a past perfect could be used, because after all both events are still in the past.  However, past perfect adds clarity and is a very useful tool.

It is always wrong to use past perfect when you should use past simple.  "I'm tired because I had gone to bed late last night" is **wrong**, because you are tired now.

---

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Some_Guy for sharing your thoughts about this. You helped me and those people who are confused about this as well :) Merci beaucoup monsieur!

Comment: @Francois  no problem.  What was the context you had in mind here?  As rathony said, "I think" will probably be more appropriate if you're talking in the present.  Also, bear in mind past perfect is, in most cases, optional, but a really useful way of framing situations if you get to grips with it :)